# STORMPATH : Token is invalid because the 'issued at' time (iat) is later than the current server time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, stormpath

I'm trying to integrate Spring Security(on top of Spring Boot) with StormPath.

Everything working fine, but as soon as user successfully login following error getting thrown:

```
Sat Feb 18 12:43:27 IST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
com.stormpath.sdk.resource.ResourceException: HTTP 400, Stormpath 10012 (https://docs.stormpath.com/rest/product-guide/latest/errors.html#error-10012), RequestId 7e042da0-f5a9-11e6-afb8-22000be1c7ec: Token is invalid because the 'issued at' time (iat: 2017-02-18T07:13:27.000Z) is later than the current server time (2017-02-18T07:12:39.000Z).
```

[Error Documentation](https://docs.stormpath.com/rest/product-guide/latest/errors.html#error-10012)

But upon manually redirecting to the default auth success URL(in my case it's simply http://localhost:8080), it successflly showing logout button and that too is working.

Below is the code so far:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.apply(stormpath());
    }   
}
```

application.properties:

```
stormpath.client.apiKey.id = xxxx
stormpath.client.apiKey.secret = xxxxx
```

What else I need to do to overcome this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the token you are supplying has a wrong time stamp, it claims to be issued in the future.

The time difference is about a minute, so when you try it manually, that minute has passed, that may be the reason why the manual redirect works.

I think there is not much you can do than inform the provider of that service to adjust their server times.

Comment: Thanks a ton man....the timer issue was at my side...very silly mistake indeed but good to learn

Comment: This is correct. I work for Stormpath; all of our servers are synced to internet time automatically. I'm guessing the local server time was off.